# Error al crear una suscripción en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

En SQL Server 2008 creé una publicación para una BD distribuida pero al momento de agregar un suscriptor no puedo agregar la base de datos. Alguien sabe a qué se debe y cómo puedo solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede la identidad "CHRISTIAN-PC" alcanzar a algunos BDs?